# Unstructured data approaches and solutions

Tags: data-structures, nlp, data-science, data-warehouse

I have a lot of unstructured/semi-structured data, think, emails with basic to/from/subjects but a lot of body text containing all sorts of other kinds of data. I’m hoping to mine this to inform certain automation, insights or even heat maps if geographic data is contained.

I’m trying to approach the problem in the right way though. From a systems architecture does anyone have an “order of operations” to designing systems and processes around this?

Best I can guest:
Step 1 is to define the “bucket” to house the data
Step 2 is to apply maybe a graph or general structure around the to/from/subject data, as an example.
Step 3 could be to apply NLP or maybe a Watson to mine the unstructured data for certain keywords or sentiments. The use case around what’s important to find would drive all of this.
Step 4 could then be to apply that “found” structure and build functions, automation, process from there.

Does that make any sense? Hoping I’m on the right track, but would love to hear thoughts.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of this analysis. Generally the process could be to open the files, extract all the text from them, apply NLP methods to extract information you want to have, process information if needed to get more knowledge from it and store it. Where you store it depends again on the purpose..e.g. for dashboarding of unstructured related data I enjoy working with Elastic/Kibana stack.

Comment: You could add a layer which sort of creates groups of mails with similar bodies. This would help you figure out frequency of each, you could say `type` of mail.